# How to convert \r to carrot M in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jboss, carriage-return

I've spent quite some time trying to google this issue.  However, I keep finding articles and answers to the opposite of what I want.

**System Specifications:**

- CentOS 6.7
- JBoss 4.2.3
- PostgreSQL v8.4

I'm using JBoss as a message server and storing messages into PostgreSQL database.

**Problem:**

Prior to the upgrade, messages would be stored into the database with carriage returns formatted as ^M and any database query would return the same format.

After the upgrade, messages in the log for JBoss still shows a ^M in the messages being sent through.  However, the ^M is now being populated in the database with \r.

**Reasons:**

- I have many scripts that rely on the ^M to parse out messages and
  lines.
- I want the data in the database to be the same as the data that
  resides in my logs.
- When using vim, I find that reading and locating ^M is easier than reading and locating \r.

**Update**

Encoding of the database is UTF-8.

The field I'm accessing is a text type.

Upon further testing, it seems that the \r is not actually being put into the database.

I have a Perl script that connects to the database and creates a file of records.  All these records show the ^M which I desire.

However, using a command like the following in the CLI will output records with \r:

```
psql dbName -U dbUser -c "select record from table" > records.txt
```

**Work Around**

Found a temporary work around to change the \r to a ^M.

```
psql dbName -U dbUser -t -c"select record from table" | sed 's!\\r!^M!g' > records.txt
```

In order to correctly use ^M in the sed command:

- Hold down control (ctrl)
- Press v then release v
- Press m then release m
- ^M should now be displayed and can now release the control key

Comment: Have you tried building a trigger that changes the `\r` in the string after the insert?

Comment: With what I use JBoss for, this wouldn't be feasible. I have overt a dozen servers and each JBoss app contains dozens of interfaces.  I've been looking to see if there was a PostgreSQL setting I can change without success.